# Calculate mean for only three values per row

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this:

```
mt1=matrix(1:144,ncol=12,nrow=12)
```

And I would like only to calcutate the mean only for 3 values in a row. These are the 
three first values:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,]  1   13   25
```

the mean should be `13`.

And the same for the next three values and the same for the next three values.. And so on and on until the end of rows.

I know I have to use the `apply` function, but I cannot figure out to apply the mean only to specific values that is only to a sequence of rows, and then on the next sequence of rows, and get then as a result a vector with the means of only 3 values per row.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The mean of 1, 13, and 25 should be 29?  That doesn't sound right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
> apply(mm, 1, function(x) mean(x[1:3]))
[1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Mean of 1,13,25 is not 29 but 13

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
rowMeans(mt1[,1:3])
#[1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: This would be my #1 answer.  This falls in the "there's a function for that" category.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
(mt1[,1] + mt1[,2] + mt1[,3])/3
```

but this is maybe less nice than the other answers, especially if adapted to cases where you need more columns included.